# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring

My Spring-MVC application sometimes crashes when navigating around the site, the error message I've gotten from the logs are found below. I have absolutely no idea of what is causing this and would be very thankful for any tips that'll lead me in the right direction.

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet HS threw exception
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2338)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2371)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor56.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1577)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
    at se.hs.daos.UserDAOImpl.findByName(UserDAOImpl.java:42)
    at se.hs.controllers.LoginController.checkPassword(LoginController.java:20)
    at se.hs.pagecontrollers.LoginPageController.submitForm(LoginPageController.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

What my UserDaoImpl looks like:

```
package se.hs.daos;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import se.hs.models.User;

public class UserDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDAO {

    private ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:applicationContext.xml");
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) context
            .getBean("mySessionFactory");
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(
            sessionFactory, true);

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.save(user);
    }

    public User getUserById(Integer id) {

        User userFromDB = hibernateTemplate.get(User.class, id);
        return userFromDB;
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.delete(user);
    }

    public User findByName(String name) {

        String query = "SELECT u.userId FROM User u WHERE u.userName='" + name
                + "'";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Integer> list = hibernateTemplate.find(query);

        User userFromDB = null;

        if (list.size() > 0) {
            userFromDB = getUserById(list.get(0));
        }

        return userFromDB;
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

```
    exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot release connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Already closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot release connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Already closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
    se.hsr.daos.InfoTextDAOImpl.saveInfoText(InfoTextDAOImpl.java:26)
    se.hsr.controllers.InfoTextController.saveInfoText(InfoTextController.java:31)
    se.hsr.pagecontrollers.InfoTextPageController.submitForm(InfoTextPageController.java:35)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.closeConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:95)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:474)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.aggressiveRelease(ConnectionManager.java:429)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.afterStatement(ConnectionManager.java:304)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closePreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:572)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:291)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.releaseStatement(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:82)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:60)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2176)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2656)
    org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:563)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:551)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:547)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:686)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
    se.hsr.daos.InfoTextDAOImpl.saveInfoText(InfoTextDAOImpl.java:26)
    se.hsr.controllers.InfoTextController.saveInfoText(InfoTextController.java:31)
    se.hsr.pagecontrollers.InfoTextPageController.submitForm(InfoTextPageController.java:35)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means DB SQL server is running out of connections. Server has a configuration parameter that specifies how maximum allowed connections.

This usually indicates that connections are not being closed. Are you requesting Connection objects from Hibernate in your code?

In short term, you can just increase maximum connections till this problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested, and changed the number of maxiumum connections to 2000. Now another error occurs: UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot release connection (if full stacktrace is relevant please tell me and I'll upload it.) This leads me to believe that increasing the number of maximum connections is not where the problem lies, any idea what it could be?

Comment: Yes, stack trace would help.You can also try adding this to hibernate configuration:

hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_statement

this is not a permanent solution, but if this helps we know that this is a configuration issue.

Answer (score 10):

If you increase the number of connections may fix it but there is still possibility to happen this same exception in future.

Make sure that you have defined `<property name="maxIdle" value="1" />` in your database configuration *xml* file. Also I had this same problem when I defined `<property name="maxIdle" value="1" />` it fixed my problem.

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/crm" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="15" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 9):

In MySql, check maximum no of concurrent connection using

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
```

By default it will be **151** ( 0 - 150). Then change max concurrent connection by

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 250;
```

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

In the above Tag this line is important

```
 <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />
```

will work, as it will allow only one connection for the AJAX or the DB request